# I'm using angular2 multiselect and i want to check whether any changes have occurred in the selection upon closing the selection box.What should i do?

Tags: html

```
<angular2-multiselect [data]="multiEquipmentList" name="equipmentmulti" 
#equipmentmulti="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="selectedEquipments"
[settings]="dropdownSettings" (onClose)="onClosing($event)"></angular2- 
multiselect>
```

Here i'm calling an onclose event and in that i want to check whether there is any change in values of selected things.

Comment: Are you using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-multiselect-dropdown ?

Comment: yes i'm using the same

Comment: I can't find the in-build provision for this checking. Try like: In `onOpen` event, you can store the current value after that check with the new value while `onClose`.

Comment: yeah i will try,thankyou

Comment: Ok. Update your question with the code block ( like `code` ) or someone edited your question, check & approve that.

Comment: onOpen(event){
  for(let j=0;j<=this.selectedEquipments.length;j++){
    this.oldEquipment[j]=this.selectedEquipments[j];
  }
 onClosing(event): void {for(let j=0;j<=this.selectedEquipments.length;j++){
      if(this.selectedEquipments[j]!=this.oldEquipment[j]){
        this.equipmentChange();

      }
    }
  }  can you just check whether the code that i have written is correct

Comment: Yeah, looks fine.